# Preventing access to setting at startup when using COSU

Tags: android, statusbar, cosu

We have created a COSU application using the method descried here: [HOW TO TURN YOUR ANDROID APPLICATION INTO A KIOSK](https://snow.dog/blog/kiosk-mode-android). We need a way to compeletly prevent the phone users from accessing anything but apps we authorize. It works very well but have one problem: when the phone reboots, for a few seconds before our app starts and hide all controls, the Android status bar is visable and operational. If the user opens it and clicks the setting button, our app does not start and the user can freely change any setting. Also, in this state he can access the frequently used apps and start unauthorized apps.
Is there any way to prevent it? Even if just to make sure our app starts in this states would be enough, since the user will not have time enough to change anything.

Thanks,
Eyal Hasson

Comment: Make/model and version of Android OS the devices are running?

Comment: We use version 9 and up of Android, since we need to start 3rd party apps in COSU. This behaviour happens with various models of devices (Samsung, Nokia etc).

Comment: Is this with or without a screen lock pin?

Comment: I tried with both screen pin lock on or off.